# layout alignment: landscape vs portrait

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone tell me why is the text in this layout is centered horizontally while in landscape mode, but becomes left-aligned in portrait mode?

**EDIT:**
Its that way because there's no pixel limit specified for text width (ie 500dip). So if its wrap_content, android simply flows the text across all of available space. I guess its a "correct" behaviour for a text component, but completely unwanted.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressLayout2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:text="@string/splash_text"
        android:id="@+id/heading_splash_text" android:textSize="45dip"
        android:textColor="#A00000" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:paddingBottom="70dip"
        android:paddingTop="50dip" android:typeface="normal" android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with some of the changes from the first answer, but I assume since you have 'wrap_content' on the linear layout, and you don't have the namespace thing on there, this layout is inside some other stuff.

First, you pretty much need the 'fill_parent' width, even if you don't do height.  Where the gravity should be specified is generally confusing, but the following works.  I added a background color on the text so you can see where that is relative to everything else.

Add back in padding if needed.

```
<LinearLayout
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="Some text"
          android:textSize="45dip"
          android:textColor="#A00000"
          android:typeface="normal"
          android:background="#444444"
          android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressLayout2"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="test"
    android:id="@+id/heading_splash_text" android:textSize="45dip"
    android:textColor="#A00000" 
  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:typeface="normal" android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think the reason your code is left aligned in portrait mode is the linearlayout is wrap_content, I think its parent control is putting it on the left side when in portrait mode.